# Workflow To Send Out Task Every WeekDay To Nominated People

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, designer-workflow, task-list

I have a requirement to create a workflow that generates a task once per day and sends the task as an email notification to the nominated person for that day (Monday to Friday).

The process is that the nominate person needs to do some checks on a daily basis and needs to be reminded to do them.

Example:

Bill gets sent the email notification on Monday.
Mandy emailed on Tuesday.
Sarah notified it's her turn on Wednesday.
Barry notified on Thursday.
James on Friday.

But the group and order could change from week to week (but may also stay the same) so it needs to be configurable.

How would I create this workflow in SharePoint Designer for SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Workflow is not the ideal technical solution for this requirement. If possible use a timer job that runs every day and process based on a configuration list.

I will provide step on how to implement this via a workflow, but it will be tricky to implement

You can create a custom list with following fields

1. User - Person field
2. Order - Number field

Now you can enter the details on this list based on order etc.

Next create a workflow associated to that list and set it to be started manually.

1. Edit the workflow and add following logic
2. Create a loop which iterates following steps
3. Check today's date and get the weekday.
4. Get the list item where order = weekday
5. From above you will get the user, Use sent email activity or create a task (which will automatically sent email)
6. Pause 24 hours

Comment: I thought this is what workflow is for - sending recurring tasks to people.

Comment: How do I get the weekday into a variable in your proposed answer?

Comment: @motionpotion take a look at this http://nishon.blogspot.com/2013/06/get-day-of-week-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: you also refer to "Create a loop which iterates following steps" - how is this loop created in default SharePoint Designer 2010?

Comment: Using that method in nishon.blog requires the workflow to run on an item.  I am not running this workflow on any item.  It needs to run as a site workflow.

Comment: @motionpotion For loop you can check this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24589.build-a-loop-workflow-using-sharepoint-2010.aspx. Its tricky as I stated on my answer. `nishon` blog will give you the formula on how to extract `weekday` the logic can be applied on `list` as well as `site` workflows.